# xml in flash actionscript couldn't loaded due to wordpress permalinks

Tags: actionscript-3, wordpress, flash-cs4

i'm new bee in flash actionscript. i want to load xml file to show some text. I used to embed flash object in wordpress. i create a newfolder in root of wordpress like wordpress/flash. xml files are exist in flash folder. i want to load those xml files on runtime in action script. i'm using this code

var xml_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   xml_loader.load( new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/flash/page_1.xml"));

but it's not working at live, i run .swf file locally it's done well and load data from live site but as i upload it to the live server and try to use it there it's stuck to loading...

please help me on this issue

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a cross-domain policy file at the root of your site:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Also, having a browser tracer for debugging is quite helpful when developing:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashtracer/ (add-on)

Lastly, check if any error is being dump in the browser console:

- Chrome: View -> Developer -> Developer Tools
- Firefox: Tools -> Web Developer -> [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) (add-on)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "base" attribute to embed XML driven swf in wordpress.. Here is the solution http://masterblogster.com/how-to-embed-swf-file-in-wordpress-that-loads-xml-file/